# Received memory warning objective c

Tags: objective-c

I get Received memory warning 3 times and then the app crash.

I have a slider that need to change blur value into UIImageView image. 
I try to work with dispatch_async and clean the image memory with   imageView.image =nil; but the problem not solved.

this code call from uislider:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
      {
       imageView.image =nil;
       imageView.image  = [self blurImage:originalImage withValue:value];
      });




-(UIImage *)blurImage:(UIImage *)theImage withValue:(nullable id)value
{
  CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
  [gaussianBlurFilter setDefaults];
  CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[theImage CGImage]];
  [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
  [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:value forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];

  CIImage *outputImage = [gaussianBlurFilter outputImage];
  CIContext *context   = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
  CGImageRef cgimg     = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[inputImage extent]];
  UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

  return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the assumption would be you did not release the CIImageRef cgimg. This might tend to add up memory.

```
-(UIImage *)blurImage:(UIImage *)theImage withValue:(nullable id)value
{
  CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
  [gaussianBlurFilter setDefaults];
  CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[theImage CGImage]];
  [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
  [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:value forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];

  CIImage *outputImage = [gaussianBlurFilter outputImage];
  CIContext *context   = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
  CGImageRef cgimg     = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[inputImage extent]];
  UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
  //Release the core image reference
  CGImageRelease(cgimg)
  return image;
}
```